# Intermittent failure executing on USB insert with auto-mount on Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb-drive, systemctl, automount

I've set up a raspberry pi to execute a command if a USB stick is inserted, and the command calls an executable on the stick.

This works about 80% of the time, but intermittently fails - seemingly at random. Because of the unpredictability I assume this is a race condition, however I'm not too familiar with where the risks are as I've pieced together the approach from information online. Most of the information comes from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/679600/212083).

The USB stick is auto-mounted with the following entry in `/etc/fstab`. I'm aware of the risk of /dev/sda1 changing but that does not appear to be the problem here:

```
/dev/sda1 /media/usb vfat defaults,rw,nofail,user,umask=000 0 0
```

A service waits for the USB to mount with the following configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=USB Mount Trigger
Requires=media-usb.mount
After=media-usb.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=media-usb.mount
```

`media-usb.mount` comes from `systemctl list-units -t mount`, and /script.sh calls the USB stick's executable.

In failure cases, where the USB's executable is not called, I see the following from `systemctl status service_name`:

```
Nov 15 22:49:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for USB Mount Trigger.
Nov 15 22:49:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: service_name.service: Job service_name.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

In these cases if I execute `systemctl list-units -t mount` I do not see `media-usb.mount` and my USB stick is not mounted to /media/usb.

I think that an error / race condition in service_name.service causing the USB mount to die, because (I believe) a successful mount is required to trigger the service. If the USB is never inserted, `systemctl status service_name` simply reports `Active: inactive (dead)`, so something *is* triggering the service to try to execute.